# Monty Hall Problem Solve Using Detailed Algebra

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem, monty-hall

I have been searching the monty hall problem for two days now and I generally understand it but I am having a very hard time solving the monty hall problem using Bayes's theory. I do not know what form of the theory should I use and how to apply it.

I would be very delighted if someone displays how to solve the monty hall problem using bayes's theory while showing algebraic step and explaining it. I desperately need to know and its been about 30 hours trying to research and solve it but I am not able.

Thank you.